# my bootstrap navbar is not working in my html?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to build a very basic navbar using bootstrap but its not working, I used bootstrap property navbar navbar-inverse, which is supposed to insert a black navbar but its not working.[screenshot of code and my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRSqe.png)

Comment: can you also include your css?

Comment: I haven't written anything in CSS yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your link seems to point in the wrong direction

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Properly value other links

```
<script src="../js/someFile.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by wrong direction ? and possible solution for it

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Lifestyle store</a>
    
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign up</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: It works but can you tell me what's the problem with my code? Thanx for this anyways.